# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el fondo de botones en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, botón

**Buenas a todos!**
Estoy aprendiendo Android y en el proceso me he puesto a practicar, entonces quiero hacer lo siguiente
Un botón que cambie cada cierto tiempo el color de fondo y pasado un segundo vuelva a su color original. Si el color es diferente de blanco o del por defecto que me cuente 1

Tengo ya la función del conteo, solo no sé como recibir el color por defecto ¿Como sería?
Y lo que no consigo por nada es cambiar el fondo del botón desde una función, lo he intentado con setBackground(Y le paso un color) pero es que me lo deja horrible, me cambia todo el cuadrado del botón como ven en la foto
Quiero que me cambie pero bien, con el diseño que ya tiene.
También he intentado cambiar el estilo pero no sé como hacerlo por código, solo puedo desde el XML ...

Alguna ayudita por favor !
Gracias de antemano

[image: Mi XML]
[image: La parte donde quiero hacer las funciones]
[image: Así me cambia el fondo, pero quiero conservar la forma del botón]

Comment: Hola .Sebas Saldaña., te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!
em>

Comment: Gracias por editar @sebassaldaña , super recomendable agregar el layout y código como texto en la pregunta, ya que como imagen este en ocasiones no es legible.